# How to create search/autocomplete functionality using mongodb and expressjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

So basically I want to create a search functionality for my users schema. I would take in a query for a user based on their name and return relevant users.

For example:

query = "leo", response = ["leonel messi", "leonardo dicaprio", ...]

**I already tried using the text index but since that requires entire words to be inputted, it doesn't fit my constraints since a query will most likely be characters rather than entire words**.

So essentially Im looking to make an autocomplete which returns relevant users based on some input from the user.

How could I accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898139/partial-string-matching-in-mongodb

Comment: You can make use of regex. MongoDb supports regex queries to perform string pattern matching. This might be helpful https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#mongodb-query-op.-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by Dov Rine and rajabraza in the comments, I could simply use a regex to find make such an implementation.

Code:

```
const searchResults = await Users.find({ name: { $regex: `^${req.params.name}`, $options: 'i' } }).select(["name"]);
```